# StackLayout isVisible parameter never gets updated from Binding in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

**Problem**

My `StackLayout` is always visible. The `isBusy` seems to work because my `ActivityIndicator` is not running.

**Version**

I use Xamarin.Forms in `xamarin.forms.4.6.0.494-pre2`. I need to run the pre release version due to the Surface Duo SDK which requires this kind of alpha Xamarin.Forms Version.

**Code Base ViewModel**

```
bool isBusy = false;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return isBusy; }
    set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
}
```

**Code Page View Model**

```
public void LoadData()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    LoadAsync();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

**Code XAML**

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <!-- Animated spinner -->
    <ActivityIndicator Color="{StaticResource PrimaryReduced}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
    <!-- Text -->
    <Label Text="Loading ..." />
</StackLayout>
```

**Update: Other things I tried**

I read a lot that this was a malfunction behavior in prior versions of Xamarin.Forms. That's why I tried to workaround this behavior by setting the `opacity` value to 0 of my `StackLayout`.

```
Opacity="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToLoadingViewOpacityValueConverter}}"
```

But this custom converter never gets called.

**Update 2: Source code**

- [XAML Page](https://github.com/tscholze/xamarin-road-to-surface-duo/blob/feature/loading-view/rTsd/rTsd/Views/MasterDetailPage.xaml)
- [Page view model](https://github.com/tscholze/xamarin-road-to-surface-duo/blob/feature/loading-view/rTsd/rTsd/ViewModels/ItemsViewModel.cs)
- [Base view model](https://github.com/tscholze/xamarin-road-to-surface-duo/blob/feature/loading-view/rTsd/rTsd/ViewModels/BaseViewModel.cs)

Comment: Let's break down your question here a little, so you have a Stack that has a loader and a label that says the page is loading you want to show this on the basis of an `IsBusy ` flag now what I need to know are two simple things. `IsBusy` properties location i.e. xaml.cs/viewmodel or whatever and the context in which this layout is i.e. under a listview or not or some other binding context If any!

Comment: yes. the IsBusy flag is located in the Base class of the page's BindingContext which is a viewmodel.

Comment: @FreakyAli I justed added links to the related classes on GitHub. Please see "Source code" section in the original post

Comment: Is the Stacklaoyout invisible, if you don't set IsBusy to true?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe no, it's always visible. Its also visible if I set all occurences of `IsBusy` to false.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this issue in a minimal project?

Comment: Try replacing the `LoadAsync()`with `await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000)` and see if the `ActivityIndicator` runs for 2 seconds

Comment: @Benl thanks for the tip. NO it does not appear. Okay that really weird it seems that the value is for some properties always true (visible) but for others always false (activity indicator)?

Comment: This might indicate that the `BindingContext` is not set or propagated down to all views/layouts/controls (please note that you have a custom view with a `BindingContext` that might not be set). Some platforms might indicate not found properties in the debug output. The default value of properties might vary, but I think the default values are documented, at least for base classes (for example a `StackLayout` is a `Layout` where `IsVisible`  by default is true).

Comment: Yes @Benl this wa sa good point, I think I found my problem, I have to dig a little bit deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you. It was a mix of what @sven-michael-stübe and @benl said.

- I forgot that the overall page has no view model. I moved the loading
  view to the list view and not the parent container.
- My source did not await the finishing of the tasks due to a wrong
  usage / understanding of the await operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your IsBusy is set to false immediately, because you do not await your loading methods (fire and forget).

Actions needed:

- make LoadData() async
- change return of your loading methods from void to Task
- await the loading methods in your LoadData()
- read some articles about "why to avoid async void"

See:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await LoadTweetsAsync();
        await LoadArticlesAsync();
        await LoadVideosAsync();

        // or Task.WaitAll(LoadTweetsAsync(), LoadArticlesAsync(), LoadVideosAsync()); if it should be done im parallel

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private async Task LoadTweetsAsync()
    {
    }

    private async Task LoadArticlesAsync()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first guess but in this case the loading view should never be visible because `isBusy`  is always" false?

Comment: ahh I see. Then consider my answer "a additional hint to best practice"